# Draw a truncated-cone-based vortex in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to make a rudimentary model for the a coronal hole in my mathematics thesis. I am looking to create a plot where the radial direction of the cylinder increases with proportionally with the height and then I would like to add twists in the $(\theta, z)$ direction either explicitly or with lines and arrows along the surface.

Currently I have only been able to produce a normal cylinder.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Cylinder
x=np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
z=np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
Xc, Zc=np.meshgrid(x, z)
Yc = np.sqrt(1-Xc**2)

# Draw parameters
rstride = 20
cstride = 10
ax.plot_surface(Xc, Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, rstride=rstride, cstride=cstride)
ax.plot_surface(Xc, -Yc, Zc, alpha=0.2, rstride=rstride, cstride=cstride)

ax.set_xlabel("X")
#ax.set_ylabel("Y")
fig.gca().set_ylabel(r'$\theta$')
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
plt.figure(figsize=(200,70)) #sets the size of the plot
#plt.show()
```

[image: Cylinder]

Comment: A cone is axially symmetric. How can you add a twist "directly"? It would look all the same, no?

Comment: I am thinking a vortex - if we have that the radial component is increasing with heright then we can have the fluid rotating around the object, forcing the body to twist.

Comment: For rotationally symmetric objects using cylindrical coordinates makes sense. Apart, there is no z-dependence in the code. Are you asking for the formula of a conical frustum? Is this more a math question?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Essentially yes, what I need to do is vary the z component such that as z increases then r (x) will increase proportionally. I am struggling with how I would go about doing this?

Yes It would be a conical frustum essentially - I did not know the name of it!